# Mockito verify lambda is called n-times

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda, mockito

I need to test if a lambda function is called n-times from a service instance.

I have a Service class, that interact with the repository, when an error occur on retriving data from repository the service should retry until a max number of retries is reached so I have implemented as follow:

```java
interface Repository {
   Collection<String> getData();
}

public class RetryHelper<T> {

    private Integer retries;

    public RetryHelper(Integer retries) {
        this.retries = retries;
    }

    public interface Operation<T> {
        T doIt() throws Exception;
    }

    public T doWithRetry(Operation<T> operation) throws Exception {
        int remainRetries = retries;
        do {
            try {
                return operation.doIt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (remainRetries == 0) {
                    throw e;
                }
                //TODO: wait before retry
                remainRetries--;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
}

class Service {
   @Inject
   Repository repo;

   private final RetryHelper<Collection<String>> retryHelper;

   public Collection<String> callService() {
        try {
            Collection<String> res = retryHelper.doWithRetry(() ->
                repo.getData());
            return res;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw (CustomException) e;
        }
   }

}
```

I need to test using Mockito that `repo.getData()` is called n-times when error occurs. I can change the `Service` code and the `RetryHelper`, so I am open to suggestions.

I have try to implment the test following tutorials and documentations:

```java
public class ServiceTest {

    @Inject
    Service service;

    @InjectMock
    Repository repository;

    @InjectMock
    RetryHelper<Collection<String>> retryHelper;


    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<RetryHelper.Operation<Collection<String>>> operation;

    @BeforeEach
    void init_mocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void shouldRetryIfDataQueryFailsForNonFatalError() throws Exception {
        when(repository.getData())
            .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Runtime Exception"));

        service.callService();

        verify(retryHelper).doWithRetry(operation.capture());

        verify(repository, times(2)).getData();

    }
}
```

The test fail with message that `getData()` is never called.

Comment: What is `algoMappingRepository` ? Just by looking at your code I'd say it won't run because its undefined.

Comment: Your `RetryHelper<Collection<String>> retryHelper` is a mock, it doesn't do anything, so when service invokes `doWithRetry` nothing happens since there is no behaviour setup for it.

Why not instead of mocking you create a real instance of `RetryHelper` and pass it to service?

Comment: @SchreiberLex it's a typo of copy and past from editor

Comment: @AdwaitKumar It should be a mock otherwise the first verify dosen't work and I can't take capure. I have read it from mockito tutorials

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have finally found the solution without using `Captor`

```java
public class ServiceTest {

    @Inject
    Service service;

    @InjectMock
    Repository repository;

    @Inject
    RetryHelper<Collection<String>> retryHelper;


    @Test
    void shouldRetryIfDataQueryFailsForNonFatalError() throws Exception {
        when(repository.getData())
            .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Runtime Exception"));
        
        try {
           service.callService();
        } catch(Exception e) {
             verify(repository, times(2)).getData();
        }

    }
}
```